# JavaFX scroll background with moving character

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I'm making a game in scenebuilder and JavaFX, and I wanted to make the background scroll once the character got about half way through the screen. Could anyone give me an idea on how to go about doing this? Thank you so much!

Edit: I am able to get the picture to translate when the player moves, but the background just cuts off once the window moves. Is there a way for the window to have the whole background, but only display part of it, so when I translate the picture, it just moves on to the next part of the background?

Answer (score 0):

There may be better ways to do this, but I made it to where once the player reaches a certain point by moving, the background will translate(setTranslateX method) along with the player. I also had to make the scenebuilder window I was working in big enough to encompass the whole background. This solved all my problems. Hope this helps anyone who may have a similar issue!